# can't create cvblobslib.lib

Tags: opencv, blob

I downloaded the latest cvblobslib.
I tried to load the cvblobslib.dsw in Visual c++ 2010 Express and it says it needs to convert it, but then it says it can't load the cvblobslib.dsp and then to remove it. 
At the end it opens an empty project.

So how can I compile this library with Vc2010 Express?

If this is not possible with Express, could someone post the compiled cvblobslib.lib?
thank you

Comment: I also faced the same problem...I implemented the algo whic thy use with OpenCV..here is the link to the algo....http://www.iis.sinica.edu.tw/papers/fchang/1362-F.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I found the cvblobslib.lib here:
http://www.technical-recipes.com/2011/object-detection-using-the-opencv-cvblobslib-libraries/#comment-2906
at the end of the tutorial.

So, I solved my problem.

Anyway if someone knows how to compile cvblobslib in VC c++ 2010 Express, it could be also useful.

Comment: Thanks for the help!! Finally I cant found the cvblobslib.lib =D